# Check if user is logged in without asking for permissions - facebook

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk, permissions

I created an App on Facebook, but before I ask for permissions I want to check if the User is logged in and do some tasks.

I tried this:

```
    $facebook   = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => $app_id,
            'secret' => $secret,
            'cookie' => true
        ));


    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($user) {
      echo 'logged in';
    } else {
      echo 'not logged in';
    }
```

But it always ask for permissions.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in your minimal code that could lead to asking for permissions.

Comment: I know, but he ask for Personal Informations :\

Comment: Who is “he”?
Again: There is not even a login/connect to your app implemented in your code, so your problem is absolutely not reproducible by the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxx', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'YOUR_URL/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });


    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    //User Is Logged In and authorized
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            //User is Logged in and not authorized
        } else {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        }
    });
};
</script>
```